# Android app for sending GPS coordinates to server is crashing

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask, gps

I am building one android app, which sends GPS coordinates to server, but it is showing gps coordinates after that it is crashing immediately, not sending coordinates to server at all.

my MainActivity.java is

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{


private TextView latituteField;
  private TextView longitudeField;
  private LocationManager locationManager;
  private String provider;
  String lat;
String lng;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
    longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);

    // Get the location manager
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
    // default
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    // Initialize the location fields
    if (location != null) {
      System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
      onLocationChanged(location);
    } else {
      latituteField.setText("Location not available");
      longitudeField.setText("Location not available");
    }
  }

  /* Request updates at startup */
  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
  }

  /* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
  }




  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
     lat = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
     lng = Double.toString (location.getLongitude());
    latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
    longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
    longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
    LoadServerASYNC task = new LoadServerASYNC();
    task.execute();


       }



  @Override
  public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  @Override
  public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  }

  @Override
  public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  private class LoadServerASYNC extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        postData(lat,lng);
         StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
          HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        return null;
    }

    public void postData(String currLat, String currLon) { 
        // List with arameters and their values

        String Text2 = "String is: " +

        "Latitud = " + currLat +

        "Longitud = " + currLon;

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Text2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.url.com/*.php");
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myusername", currLat));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mypassword", currLon));
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();    

        try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            responseText = responseText.trim();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }
         }
         }
```

Here is my logcat

```
 01-21 06:16:17.400: I/System.out(1107): Provider gps has been selected.
    01-21 06:16:17.630: D/gralloc_goldfish(1107): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
    01-21 06:16:17.790: W/dalvikvm(1107): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught       exception (group=0xb4a15ba8)
    01-21 06:16:17.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1107): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    01-21 06:16:17.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1107): Process: com.example.gpsexample2a, PID: 1107
    01-21 06:16:17.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1107): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error   occured while executing doInBackground()
    01-21 06:16:17.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
    01-21 06:16:17.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
    01-21 06:16:17.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
    01-21 06:16:17.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    01-21 06:16:17.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    01-21 06:16:17.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    01-21 06:16:17.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    01-21 06:16:17.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
    01-21 06:16:17.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1107): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
    01-21 06:16:17.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
    01-21 06:16:17.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
    01-21 06:16:17.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:327)
    01-21 06:16:17.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:92)
    01-21 06:16:17.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:241)
   01-21 06:16:17.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):  at com.example.gpsexample2a.MainActivity$LoadServerASYNC.postData(MainActivity.java:143)
   01-21 06:16:17.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):  at   com.example.gpsexample2a.MainActivity$LoadServerASYNC.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:128)
   01-21 06:16:17.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):  at com.example.gpsexample2a.MainActivity$LoadServerASYNC.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1) 
   01-21 06:16:17.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288) 
   01-21 06:16:17.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove this line from your postData method

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Text2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You cant call Toast method in `doInBackground(String... arg0)`

or use [Handler](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)

Comment: or use a handler to do the job for you

Comment: @alecnash agree with you

Comment: @alecnash can u please tell me how to use handler here

Comment: [RTFM!](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

Comment: @user3209703 Please go through tutorial link posted in my edited answer to get idea about handler implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Text2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

in  postData method is the cause .You shouldn`t perform UI-Task on AsyncTask class "doInBackground()" method.
But you can display Toast from its other method like "onPreExecute()" , "onProgressUpdate()", "onPostExecute()" methods.To know , how to properly use AyncTask class refer [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is releated to this line of code:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Text2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This code is releated to the UI contest and android want to run it this contest and not in a background thread.

For this reason there are this log:

> Exception: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()